# tricky: how to check NULL in pdo?

Tags: pdo, null, blob

this code works fine, it gets an image from a DB and writes it into bild.png:

```
$verbindung = verbinde_mit_db(); # verbindet mit der DB und erledigt die Fehlerbehandlung   
$pdostatement = $verbindung->   prepare("select $s from tbbilder WHERE id_bild = $id");
$pdostatement->bindParam(1, $autorenid);   

try {
$pdostatement->execute();
    }
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $meinText .= "<br>PDO Exception <br>select $s from tbbilder WHERE id_bild = $id <br>";    
    $meinText .= print_r($e, true);
            }
$pdostatement->bindColumn(1, $lob,  PDO::PARAM_LOB);
file_put_contents('bild.png', $lob);  #file_put_contents Schreibt einen String in eine Datei, also hier "$lob" in bild.png     

$verbindung = null;  # DB Verbindung schließen  

return $ok; #### ====> shall be 1 or zero for no image found, how to do it? I tried many ways
```

Comment: Can't you rephrase your question? It is very confusing. Dor starter, I fail to see what does NULL to do with this question

Answer (score 0):

finally I found a solution, here it comes:
file_put_contents is not a only a "stand-alone" thing, but is able to return the bytes, it has written. So if there is a $lob, something is written, right?

So you change the lob-saving-line above into:
$size = file_put_contents($filename, $lob);
.......

the trigger, if there is a new file or not is this return: it returns either the file name or an empty thing:
if ($size == 0) { $filename="";}
return $filename;